# Wordpress multi site

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I new with Wordpress.

I install Wordpress and switch it to be multisite.

Question:

In the future, can I move specific site from my multi site to stand alone Wordpress installation?

How the sites of Wordpress saved in Database?

How can backup and recover specific site in the multisite?

Thanks,
Shlomit

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can move site out of network and use it as standalone install.
2. There are some shared DB tables and then each site has prefixed standard WP DB tables.
3. The same that you do for individual WP install.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have link to page that explain how can I move one site out? also what is the best way to backup my wordpress sites?

Comment: There you go few links that explain how to move site out of multisite network:
https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-migrate-db-pro/doc/extracting-subsite-multisite-create-new-single-site-install/
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/moving-wordpress-moving-a-site-out-of-a-multisite-network--cms-22772
You can see info about best backup plugins here: http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/7-best-wordpress-backup-plugins-compared-pros-and-cons/